# Solve sequence with java reqursion

Tags: java, рекурсия

Я сейчас изучаю рекурсию, наткнулся на задачу, долго не могу никак решить.

X = 1 + 1/2 + 1/(2*3) + 1/(2*3*4) + 1/(2*3*4*5) .....

Как решить это без условных операторов и желательно рекурсией?

Пробовал этот код, но он работает некорректно

public static double test1(double n) {
    if (n == 1) return 1;
    return (1.0 / (n * test1(n - 1))) + test1(n - 1);
}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow на русском! Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian. As follows from the name, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). This question may get closed soon, but if you choose to translate, it will surely be reopened, once the translation is done.

Answer (score 1):

1/n! = [1/(n - 1)!]/n

```
public static double factor(double n) {
  if (n == 1) return 1;
  return factor(n - 1) / n;
}

public static double sum(double n) {
  double res = 0;
  for(int i = 1; i <=n; i++)
    res += factor(i);
  return res;
}
```

Comment: на каждом шаге вычисление факториала не очень хорошая идея -  сложность алгоритма превращается в квадратичную + возможные проблемы с переполнением.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov вычисление факториала через рекурсию сама по себе не очень хорошая идея. А если автору нужна именно рекурсия, до 99%, что это тестовое задание на рекурсию

Answer (score 1):

Try my solution:

```
public static BigDecimal sum(int n) {
    BigDecimal result = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    BigDecimal factor = BigDecimal.ONE;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        factor = factor.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(i));
        result = res.add(BigDecimal.ONE.divide(factor, MathContext.DECIMAL128));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: на [ru.so] принято задавать вопросы и отвечать на русском языке. не нужно отвечать на английском.